# In VBA, how do I call the value of a cell that's populated by a reference formula

Tags: vba, excel, email

Every day, I get a list of files that I have to email different people customized emails depending on different parameters (e.g., if a file hasn't moved in X days they'll get one email, if a file is at a certain milestone they'll get a different email, etc)

This is how I approached it, which may not have been the best way, but I wanted to avoid doing all the sorting logic in VBA because I'm not as familiar with it.

First, I paste the list and parameters into a worksheet, and then I have a separate worksheet for each custom email, using some nested IF statements to show each file on the correct worksheet, like this:

```
=IF(AND(Broker!$Q3="N",PasteExpiringLocks!$D3<>"",PasteExpiringLocks!$B3=TODAY(),VALUE(PasteExpiringLocks!$J3)>29),PasteExpiringLocks!B3,"")
```

All of this works how I want it, each file gets grouped together how I want it.

Next, I want to use VBA to then send out emails for each file on each worksheet, and every file on a single worksheet will get the same general email, except with cell references for specific parameters like name and file number.

```
 Worksheets("DisclosuresCancel").Select
    For Each cell In Columns("N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
       If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value) = "y" Then

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value
                .Cc = Cells(cell.Row, "O").Value
                .Subject = Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value & ", " & Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value & ", Expiring Locks - " & Date
                .Body = "Sample Email"
            .Send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell
```

This code is also working fine with multiple worksheets in a test file I was running, however, the next step is giving me trouble, because in the test file I was using actual values to test the email VBA code, but the actual file uses formulas. So, for example when it's looking for the `.To = Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value` it just sees the formula that references the email address on a different sheet, and not the result of that formula.

I have a "simple" solution, which is to run a macro that does a copy>special paste on each sheet before running the email script... but that clears out all the formulas, and I'd have to keep a backup file in case it gets saved or something, and that just seems like a workaround for not knowing how to code it correctly.

Is there a simple way that when referencing a cell value like `Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value` that it will just evaluate the formula in the cell and use the result? I tried using the Evaluate function in VBA, but that didn't seem to be working right either for doing multiple rows.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I've made some changes that MIGHT work, but I'm currently getting an Error 91 when I try to set the cells I'm referencing as variants. Here's how I've got my VBA setup at the beginning:

`Option Explicit

Sub Email()

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim ato As Variant, acc As Variant, LoanNum As Variant, ExpDate As Variant, _
    Milestone As Variant, BorrName As Variant, YNmail As Variant, Lofficer As Variant, LOA As Variant


ato = Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value
acc = Cells(cell.Row, "O").Value
LoanNum = Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
ExpDate = Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
Milestone = Cells(cell.Row, "G").Value
BorrName = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
YNmail = Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value
Lofficer = Cells(cell.Row, "E").Value
LOA = Cells(cell.Row, "F").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


On Error GoTo cleanup`
```

After that, it goes into the email code (see further above) but replacing the cell references with their new variables like: `.Subject = LoanNum & ", " & BorrName & ", Expiring Locks - " & Date`, but when I debug the code it stops at the `ato = Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value` line and gives an error 91. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried `.Text`?

Comment: The statement `For Each cell In Columns("N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` only iterates `cell` that have constants that is not formula. Thus this would never return a `cell` that has formula that creates the email address.

Comment: Are you sure there is a formula in column N?  I.e. when you look at the cell does it show an actual email address, and you only see the formula when you edit the cell?  Or are you seeing the "formula" even when just looking at the cell on the screen.  (I am suspecting that someone had formatted the cell as "Text" and then typed a formula in, which will therefore just be interpreted as text and not a formula.)

Comment: FWIW - the correct way of getting the value of a cell (i.e. what has been calculated by the formula in the cell) is to use the **`.Value`** property, or to use the `.Value2` property (if you don't want the value returned as a `Date` or `Currency` type), or to use the `.Text` property (if you want the value as a string after applying any cell formatting).  So, in your situation, the use of `.Value` is the correct method.

Comment: .value is what I'm using, and none of the fields are formatted to text, they're all formatted to general, except for two: dates and number

Comment: (a) A field can contain text and still be formatted as `General` (e.g. type `'=A1+1` into a cell and see what happens, or format a cell as `Text` and then enter `=A1+1` and then change it back to `General`) (b) However, if your cell is displaying the email address and not the formula, then (as @bulbus mentioned) your code won't be reaching the statement containing `Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value` because it isn't a constant.  (c) Perhaps it would help if you included in the question a screenshot of your "DisclosuresCancel" sheet.

Comment: Right after the `for` statement  try putting `MsgBox(cell.address() & cell.value())`. This should resolve your issue. Keep the code as is as your original post.

Comment: Also remove temporarily `On Error Resume Next` & `On Error GoTo 0` till you resolve the issue.

Comment: Also just a note that your `simple solution` mentioned in your post is working because you converted the column N to constant cells. Refer my original comment.

Comment: Simple solution is change `For Each cell In Columns("N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` to `For Each cell In Columns("N").Cells` and everything should work fine. But I would like you to resolve this by trying my earlier `MsgBox` comments.

Comment: Re your last edit - you can't use `cell.Row` until you have created `cell` (in your `For Each cell In Columns("N").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` block)

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning cell values to variables before using them in `With OutMmail`.

```
Dim ato as Variant, acc as Variant, Subja as Variant, Subjb as Variant
ato = Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value
acc = Cells(cell.Row, "O").Value
Subja = Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value
Subjb = Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value
```

then later on use them as follows:

```
With OutMail
    .To = ato
    .Cc = acc
    .Subject = Subja & ", " & Subjb & ", Expiring Locks - " & Date
    .Body = "Sample Email"
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: I did all that, and changed all the references, but now I'm getting an Error 91, since I didn't "Set" something.. but I don't know what I'd need to Set. Another question: If I set those variants up like `ato = Cells(cell.Row, "N").Value` will that work across multiple sheets? Like, as long as the code selects a new worksheet, will it work and reference the cell from that sheet?

Comment: As long as the code select new Worksheet before adding new value to variable, it will work.

Comment: I updated my original question to show how I initialize my VBA, can you tell me why I'm getting an error 91 when I'm trying to set my first variable? (BTW, thanks for all your help so far!)